# I look for 2 commutative algebra counterexamples

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, noetherian

I'm looking for an answer to these 2 trivially formulated problems:

Problem 1: Give an example of a ring $A$, an injective $A$-module homomorphism $f : M → M'$ and an $A$-module $N$ such that the homomorphism $\operatorname{id} ⊗ f : N ⊗_A M → N ⊗_A M'$ is not injective

Problem 2: Give an example of a module $M$ over a Noetherian ring $A$ such that $M_{\mathfrak p}$ is finitely generated for each $\mathfrak p ∈ \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, but $M$ is not finitely generated. $M_{\mathfrak p}$ is a localisation of M with multiplicatively closed subset being $A\setminus \mathfrak p$.

Last week I spent an hour thinking about it but did not get a result. This is not my homework so don't be afraid to help me. copies are already taken, that's why I ask here if I don't find answers in Google :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One question at a time, please. (Forum rules!)

Comment: Hint for 2. $M=\bigoplus_{p\text{ prime}}\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Comment: A *whole hour*, poor you... :)

Comment: @rschwieb I dont have a time to think a lot about every problem in mathematics. And this problem is more like interesting trick than real fundamental problem.

Comment: @MaciejFicek I don't think giving an example (or two examples) is anything at all like a "trick."  But anyhow, I was just reminded of my own graduate experience of many hours spent on particular problems or examples.  Hopefully you are ready for the time spent thinking to increase, because that's what's going to happen...

Comment: @rschwieb I spent a lot of time learning but sometimes when I get blocked, I have to go into further exercises and therefore I ask on MSE, usually trying also to explain what Ive obtain so far. In these problems it was impossible because they were 0-1 problems - You guess or You dont guess.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you can insider the canonical injection $i:I\hookrightarrow A$ of an ideal $I$ into the ring, and tensor by an $A$-module $N$ annihilated by $I$ (e.g. $A/I$: the image of the homomorphism
$$i\otimes \operatorname{1}_N; I\otimes_A N\rightarrow A\otimes_AN\simeq N$$ 
is the submodule $IN=\{0\}$, so $i\otimes \operatorname{1}_N$ is not injective  if $I\otimes_AN\ne\{0\}$, which happens for instance if $I$ is free and $N\ne \{0\}$.